# I want to insert data like text and date from HTML FORM to PHP to MYSQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, date, insert

My code is already inserting a data on the database, but only the Primary key(AUTO_INCREMENT) is the only adding. I can't get the date and the text.

Is there something wrong in my code?
Here is my code below:

HTML:

```
<form action="insertleave.php" method="post">
     <label>Date Filed:</label>
      <input type="date" name="datefiled">

      <label>Date of Leave:</label>
      <input type="date" name="leavedate">

  </div>
  <div class="medium-6 columns">
    <label>Reason of Leave:</label>
    <textarea rows="8" form="leaveform" name="reason"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="expanded button" name="formSubmit" value="File Leave">
  </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$datefiled = $_POST['datefiled'];
$leavedate = $_POST['leavedate'];
$leavereason = $_POST['leavereason'];

$config = parse_ini_file("phpconfig.ini");
$conn = mysqli_connect($config['host'], $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['dbname']);


if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


   $sql = "INSERT INTO leaves (ID, EmployeeID,DateFiled, LeaveDate, Reason)
   VALUES
   ('$ID','$EmployeeID','$DateFiled','$LeaveDate','$Reason')";


  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "OK!";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your text area, you given it a name "reason"

in your post variable, your value is "leavereason"

change the `$leavereason = $_POST['leavereason'];` to `$leavereason = $_POST['reason'];`

Answer (score 0):

In you Reason of leave text area `name` of input is different.

Your variable name are different in your `sql` query and you are assigning to different variable.

Also your `EmployeeID` is empty here. there is no input for EmployeeID from html file or you should post it to php file.

Change you php code like this.

```
<?php
$datefiled = $_POST['datefiled'];
$leavedate = $_POST['leavedate'];
$leavereason = $_POST['reason'];

$config = parse_ini_file("phpconfig.ini");
$conn = mysqli_connect($config['host'], $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['dbname']);


if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


   $sql = "INSERT INTO leaves (ID, EmployeeID,DateFiled, LeaveDate, Reason)
   VALUES
   ('$ID','$EmployeeID','$datefiled','$leavedate','$leavereason')";


  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "OK!";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```